# When using window.create how can I get the object of the original window in new window

Tags: javascript, html, postmessage

I'm playing with the new cross-window messaging api. I create a new window with window.open and I can send messages to this new window. I would like to do the reverse and be able to send message to original window from the new window.

How can I obtain the object of the original window?

Comment: You should post that as the answer cause it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.opener` in the popup to access the opener window.